# Plotar Grafico Google Chart através de dado no input

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Gente tenho um box de autocomplete, onde o usuário escreve um item e quando clicar em "Enviar" o mesmo plotará um gráfico na mesma tela (pagina).

Estou usando o Google Charts e para o autocomplete estou usando um script AJAX em JS. O Meu documento é em .php

A minha dúvida é:

```
<form autocomplete="off" action= " " > 
  <div class="autocomplete" style="width:600px;">
   <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myItem" placeholder="Item">
 </div>
 <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Eu consigo colocar a função de plotar o grafico no "action" do autocomplete, se sim como? Obrigado!

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que você quer criar? não o que você quer fazer para criar!

Comment: Claro, tenho um banco de dados que contém dados de diversas empresas e se as empresas possui uma determinada politica empregada ou não.

O gráfico irá mostrar a % que as empresas possuem determinada politica empregada. Um benchmark, por exemplo: atualmente  30% das empresas do nosso escopo empregam politica de "controle de acesso à um DataCenter".

O usuario digita em um campo (isso já esta feito) qual politica ele quer visualizar a % no grafico.

O que não estou conseguindo fazer é ao clicar em "Enviar" no campo, plotar o grafico na mesma tela.